# Multiple apache web server Redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, bind

I'm running my own DNS server and can manage my company domnain via my ISP. I have 1 public IP address

external request to www.mydomain.com and mail.domain.com is pass to my old local web server @ 192.168.0.10.

Now at the new local web server @192.168.5.100 I configure some services with name like serv1.mydomain.com, serv2.mydomain.com, etc... I also add these name into my local DNS server

I also point the external serv1.mydomain.com, serv2.mydomain.com to my public IP address

How can I redirect all the request serv1.mydomain.com, serv2.mydomain.com from out site world to my new local web server @192.168.5.100

Thanks in advanced !

Comment: What device is doing the NATing?

Comment: I use a draytek vigor2910 router

Answer (score 0):

The current situation is that you are doing NATing from your public IP to 192.168.0.10. This address belongs to the old web server.

All you have to do is to do the NATing from your public IP to 192.168.5.100 (the new web server).

The DNS names will always return the same value (your public IP).

**Updated:**

In depends on the type of services that you have on your servers. For example, you can do the following:

1- Route the HTTP port 80 (www.mydomain.com) and IMAP/POP3 ports 143/110 (mail.mydomain.com) to the IP: 192.168.0.10

2- Route the services (serv1.mydomain.com and serv2.mydomain.com) to the IP: 192.168.5.100. You need to know the ports to do the correct NATing.

If you have the same service on both servers, you have to do some application-level routing/forwarding in this case.

Comment: I want to keep running both the web server...is there any way different ?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: thank Khaled, I think I need an application-level routing/forwarding